# Selecting columns while using has_many_and_belongs_to in Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three tables, `places`, `place_user`, `users`. I want to list `users` according to the `place_user` table in Place model by using the `has_many_and_belongs_to` method. But i don't want to select all columns of users. I tried to do by below:

```
Place::find(1)->users()->get(array('name','email'));
```

**Also**:

```
Place::find(1)->users()->first(array('name','email'));
```

but they didn't work.

What is the best way to handle this?

Place model:

```
class Place extends Eloquent {
    public static $timestamps = true;

    public function users() {
        return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('user');
    }
}
```

**User model**:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public static $timestamps = true;

    public function get_updated_at_readable() {
        return date('d.m.Y / H:i:s', strtotime($this->get_attribute('updated_at')));
    }

    public function get_created_at_readable() {
        return date('d.m.Y / H:i:s', strtotime($this->get_attribute('updated_at')));
    }

    public function places() {
        return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('place','place_user');
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the `Place` and `User` model code. I have a bad feeling that your `User` model isn't extending Eloquent, or, your relations are set up incorrectly.

Comment: I added Place and User models.

Comment: I am not sure, but shouldn't `Place::users()` method also have the `place_user` pivot assigned? Also, `User::places()`, I think, should be `has_many()`. I doubt that User belongs to Place and vice versa at the same time.

Comment: There is pivot table,
`return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('user');` specify pivot table as place_user. has_many() don't use pivot table, so if I use it, I get just place ids. Also, I tried after you say to remove User::places() method, nothing change. I should say, 
`Place::find(1)->users()->get();
Place::find(1)->users;`
etc. are working. Just i couldn't specify columns.

Comment: Is there an error when you try to specify columns? And, try `->get(array('<table>.<column>', '<table>.<otherColumn>'))` notation.

Comment: No, there isn't any error. Also, I check config/error.php it wasn't closed to show error. I don't like to say but trying `->get(array('<table>.<column>', '<table>.<otherColumn>'))` didn't work, too.

Comment: Actually, [`has_many()`](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Laravel.Database.Eloquent.Model.html#275) has second parameter, so try adding it to `Place` model, `users()` method.

Comment: It's for foreign key. But, I need to handle pivot table (I think, it is just done by has_many_and_belongs_to). By the way, I tried has_many, while using it, columns can be selected.

Comment: Well, post this as an issue on Laravel's GitHub, I have no more clue what is causing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still, not working with get, first methods but select method is working:

```
Place::find(1)->users()->select(array('users.name', 'users.email'))->get();
```

Comment: ->get() will take a first parameter of a select array.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this is causing errors because one or both columns "name"/"email" are ambiguous across your Place and User tables.

As in your solution, you are able to write columns specifying tables:

```
Place::find(1)->users()->get(array('users.name','users.email'));
```